# "Override Attribute Initializers" behaviour in EA14.0 changed over "Set Run State" in EA12.5

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I observed a behviour in EA14.0 that has been changed from the behaviour in EA12.5.

## Summary

In EA12.5 when using a `Deployment Specification` one had to set the `Instance Classifier` on the `Deployment Specification` object in order to be able to set the run state (`Ctrl+Shift+R`). It was not necessary to set a `Parent` on the object. In EA14.0 one has to specify a `Parent` from which the attributes are derived that can be overridden, and I addtion the `Instance Classifier` has to be set but it can be set to an arbitrary object (not related to the `Parent`).

In the following sections I outlined the steps I executed:

## Setting a run state in EA12.5

1. Set `Instance Classifier`
   [image: Advanced|Instance Classifer context menu on object]
2. Select `Select Run State`
   [image: Features & Properties|Set Run State Menu]
3. Define `Variables` from `Instance Classifier`
   [image: Set Run State Dialogue on object]
4. Result of a `Deployment Specification`
   [image: <code>Deployment Specification</code> object with set run state]
   As we can see the actual `Instance Classifier` class is visible on the `Deployment Specification` object. It serves as the basis from which the `Variables` can be configured.

## Setting attribute initializers in EA14.0

1. When trying the same steps in EA14.0 I get the following error message:
   [image: Invoking <code>Ctrl+Shift+R</code> shortcut on object with <code>Instance Classifier</code> specified]
2. However, when I additionally specify a `Parent` on the `Deployment Specification` object I can configure the variables defined the `Parent` class.
   [image: Features & Properties|Override Initializer Attributes Menu]
3. In this case it does not matter which `Instance Classifier` I specified. In the following figure I set the `Instance Classifier` to an empty class called `Totally unrelated object` (with not attributes defined).
   [image: <code>Deployment Specification</code> object with overridden initialiser attributes]
4. Side note: when I open a model/EAP-file created in EA12.5 in EA14.0 I can still see the previously configured run states, but am not able to any more modify them (unless I set the previously assigned `Instance Classifier` to the `Parent`).

## Questions

So this seems to be a breaking change to me and my (multipart) question is:

1. Am I doing something wrong?
2. Does anyone know anything about this changed behaviour and the possible rationale behind it?
3. Does anyone know an easy trick how I can migrate all my existing `Deployment Specification` objects in my multiple models?

Thank you for your answers and suggestions!

Regards,
Ronald

Comment: Looks pretty much like a bug to me. Please report to Sparx support. What do you mean by `Parent` class, the target of a Generalization? In any way, an instance should only have an classifier to set the run state, Generalization has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You can simply link to this post when reporting a bug: http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/forms/bug_report.html

Comment: @GeertBellekens with `Parent` I mean to set the parent as shown in figure 1. And yes, setting an object as parent in the menu will make that object a target of a Generalisation.

Comment: @ThomasKilian thanks for your hint regarding a bug report. As I am not sure, whether this actually is a bug, I wanted to ask this question, as maybe someone could explain the behaviour. And yes, I will submit a bug report and post the result of it here as soon as I get a reply.

Comment: Thanks. New EA version now come with a set of free bugs too...

Comment: Seems like EA somehow conflated the "set run state" feature with the set overrides feature. Definitely a bug.

Comment: As suggested I reported this as a bug. Here is the reference number: 18058942. Will update as soon as I get a reply.

Comment: Sparx confirmed this to be a bug (id #18058942) giving this feedback: "To follow this up, this has been confirmed as an issue and lodged for correction. At this stage we do not know of any work-arounds."