# What is the difference between Override Attribute Initializers and Set Run State in Enterprise Architect and why does it behave differently?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

this is my first question on SO, so please exercise some kindness on my path to phrasing perfect questions.

On my current project I try to model deployments in EA v14.0 where I want components to be deployed on execution environments and additionally set them to some values.

However depending on how I *deploy* (as an `Deployment Artifact` or as a `Component Instance`) I get different behaviours. On `Deployment Artifacts` I am offered to `Override Attribute Initializers`. On a `Component Instance` I am offered to `Set Run State`. When I try to set an attribute on the `DeploymentArtifact` I get an error message that there is no initialiser to override. When I try to set the run state on the `Component Instance` I can set a value. However, then I get an UML validation error message, that I must not link a component instance to an execution environment:

> MVR050002 - error ( (Deployment)): Deployment is not legal for Instance: Component1 --> ExecutionEnvironment1

1. This is how I started. I created a component with a deployment specification: [image]
2. I then created a deployment diagram to deploy my component:  [image]Once as a `Deployment Artifact` and once as a `Component Instance`.
3. When I try to Override Attribute Initializers [image: Override Attribute Initializers], I get the error message `DeploymentArtifact` has no attribute initializers to override`.
4. When I try to Set Run State [image: Set Run State] I can actually enter values [image: enter values].
5. However, when I then validate my package, I get the aforementioned error message.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong or how this is supposed to work?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: there seems to be a change in behaviour from previous versions of EA and the current version of EA, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50384657/3881834. I actually filed a bug at Sparx #18058942. So maybe this is also a bug.

Comment: I think this has been discussed recently on Sparx' forum and the conclusion was (IIRC) to turn off strict connector checking.

Comment: How did you create `DeploymentArtifact::Component1`?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I dragged the `Component1` from the Project Browser to the diagram and selected "Drop As" `Artifact` (instead of `Link` or `Instance`).

Comment: It seems you have created `Name:char` manually. You are doing something very weird here and you should re-think what that is you try to achieve.

Comment: @ThomasKilian the `Name` attribute has been defined on `Component1` on not on the instance `Instance:Component1` or on the `DeploymentArtifact`. It has not been created manually.

Comment: 2nd pic shows `Name:char`. That can only be created manually with Features/Classifier Attributes.

Comment: When creating instances you don't get classifier attributes from the class.

Comment: I am using EA v14 and created the diagram as described. I additionally selected from the `Compartment Visibility` `Show Elements Compartments` dialogue the following items: `Attributes` and `Inherited Attributes` in order to make the inherited `Name` attribute *visible* on the instance. Maybe you are using a different version. Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are multiple questions here.

1. Your 2nd diagram is invalid (and probably EA should have moaned here already since it does so in V12).

   You can deploy an artifact on a node instance and use a deployment spec as association class like shown on p. 654 of the UML 2.5 specs:

[image]

But you can not deploy something on something abstract. You will need instances - on both sides.

You can silence EA about warnings by turning off strict connector checking in the options:

[image]

---

2. To answer your question in the title: Override initializers looks into the attribute list of the classifier of an object and offers the so you can set any run states (that is values of attributes at runtime). Moreover the Set Run State allows to set arbitrary key value pairs which are not classifier attributes. This is to express e.g. RAM size in Nodes or things like that.

Comment: thank your for your explanation and help. Regarding your 1st pt: I tested this with an execution environment instance and still get the same error message, so for EA deployments from an deployment artifact instance and a component instance to an execution environment instance are both invalid. Regarding your 2nd pt: I then do not understand why I cannot override values on a Deployment Artifact Instance. As far as I understand, this is an instance and the classifier in my example has attributes defined. So I should be able to override them. Did I misunderstand you? thank you again for your help

Comment: I will install a V14 test version (once again; it has more flaws than features...) and try there.

Comment: Sorry, I have an issue with the V14 installation. Will take some time :-/